# Sorting Array received from Core Data in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, nsarray, ios8, nsmanagedobject

I have a `NSManagedObject` my own class (`BPMonitor`) for my Entity - `BPMonitor`:

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

@objc(BPMonitor)
class BPMonitor: NSManagedObject {
    @NSManaged var sisPress: String
    @NSManaged var diaPress: String
    @NSManaged var hbPress: String
    @NSManaged var datePress: NSDate
}
```

In code I receive data from Core Data to array:

```
var results:[BPMonitor]=[]
...
...
```

How I can sort my array for field `datePress` (`NSDate`) in descending order?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You just need to use standard `sort` or `sorted` functions provided by Swift:

```
var results: [BPMonitor] = []

var sortedResults = sorted(results, {
    $0.datePress.compare($1.datePress) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedDescending
})
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you use an NSSortDescriptor when fetching your Core Data entities?

Comment: It lets Core Data do the work for you, and while you can sort after you retrieve, it's just an extra operation that has to take place. An NSFetchRequest takes an array of NSSortDescriptor objects, so even if you have just one NSSortDescriptor, drop it in an array and you should be ok.